# hibernate one to many query

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I have following classes-tables with onetomany relationships

People

```
 @Entity 
 public class People{ 
     @Id @Column private Integer id;
     @Column(name="FNAME")  private String fName;   
     @Column(name="LNAME")  private String lName;   
     @OnetoMany(targetEntity=Registration.class, mappedBy="pId", cascade.....)  
     private Set<Registrations> registrations;   
     //getters and setters 
  }
```

Events

```
  @Entity
  public class Events{
     @Id @Column private Integer id;   
     @Column(name="NAME")  private String name;
     @Column(name="DATE")  private Timestamp date;
    @OnetoMany(targetEntity=Registration.class, mappedBy="eId", cascade.....)  
    private Set<Registrations> registrations;   
    //getters and setters 
  }
```

Registrations

```
  @Entity
  public class Registrations{
     @Id @Column private Integer id;   
     @Manytoone @JoinColumn(name="pid" ) private Person person;
     @Manytoone @JoinColumn(name="eid" ) private Event event;
  //getters and setters 
  }
```

So in the input form when the user enters a list of "event id", I need to return a list of people who attended those events.. how to write query for this type? 
I have this so far..

> from Person p join p.registations r where r.event.id in (:eventIdlist)"

but I think it returns both person and refistration objects.. cause when I did this List person = query.list() I got cannot cast kind of error.. I just need person object list..

Comment: Tell us what the exact error message is, and show use the code which throws this exception. Besides, your mapping is wrong: mappedBy="eId" should be replaced by mappedBy="event", and mappedBy="pId" should be replaced by mappedBy="person".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct r.person from Registration r where r.event.id in (:eventIdList)
```

Comment: Nope, this one is incorrect. You can not use .event on p.registrations which represent a collection. You have to join it as the OP did.

Comment: @JB.. yes I already tried that earlier and got the illegalarguemnt exeption for trying to instantiate object on list or somekind of error

Comment: Another try, adding the disctinct.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:

```
select r.person from Registration r where r.event.id in (:eventIdList)
```

EDITED from comment: To join your other tables you could do:

```
select p
from Person p
where p.registration.event.id in (:eventIdList)
and p.peopleLanguage.language.id in (:languageIdList)
```

Comment: @Bohemian/Gaetanz.. thanks for the reply.. I'm gonna try this tmrw at work.. but I have one doubt though.. I have two more tables with onetomany relationships.. Lets say Languages(Id, Name), PeopleLanguages(Id, PersonID, LanguageId).. I can use a query similar to above to extract a list of persons who speak a list of languages.. but how can I combine these two queries.. I mean if I want a list of persons who attended some events **and** who speak some languages?

Comment: @Bohemian.. can't use p.registrations.event.. because p.registrations is a collection... similarly p.peoplelanguages..